# Tokenize a string in f#

Tags: f#

If I have an f# function that takes a string containing a sentence, what is the best way to break that string up into a list of strings, one string for each word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case the simplest answer is likely to just use the standard System.String.Split() function.

```
let split (value:System.String) = value.Split([|' '|])
```